# How do I write a function in java to return decimals to a given number of places?

Tags: java, decimal

Suppose I have a function double toDecimal(int numerator, int denominator, int places);

How would I write it so that I get the decimal value to the fixed number of places asked for?

```java
 return Math.round((double) numerator * Math.pow(10, places)) /
            (denominator * Math.pow(10, places));
```

I tried this but on testing even when I add decimals with more places the tests passed when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)  Read **all** answers.

Comment: A `double` value does not have a specific number of decimal places, at least not a modifiable one.  And because few rational numbers are exactly representable as type `double`, your hypothetical value rounded to a certain number of places often cannot be represented as a `double` whose (exact) decimal representation has an all-zero tail starting after the specified number of digits.  So what do you *really* want?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using BigDeciaml class as below:

```
double rounded = new BigDecimal(double_variable).setScale(3 /*number_of_decimals*/, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
```

Change second parameter as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 1.2232f;
    
int place = 2;
    
String s = String.valueOf(f);
String newS = s.substring(0,s.length() - place);
    
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(newS));
```

First convert your decimal number in `String`.
Get the substring be eliminating the last values.
Convert it back to a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

This, I think, is the recommended solution.

```
   String.format("%.3f", myFloat);
```

Comment: Prints three decimals

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to do the following:

```
return Math.round(((double)numerator / denominator) * Math.pow(10,places))
       / Math.pow(10,places);
```

However, it's not recommended:

1. The type `double` represents numbers in base 2, so it cannot precisely store all numbers to base 10; in other words it will store numbers to 3 decimal places only approximately.
2. Decimal places is something that is only meaningful when you print a number. Therefore, it's better to keep the whole precision and just print out at the end using `System.out.printf("%.3f", number)`